# Python program asks for input twice, doesn't return value the first time

Tags: python

Here is my code, in the `get_response()` function, if you enter 'y' or 'n', it says invalid the first time but then works the second time.
How do I fix this?

```
import random

MIN = 1
MAX = 6

def main():

    userValue = 0
    compValue = 0

    again = get_response()

    while again == 'y':
        userRoll, compRoll = rollDice()
        userValue += userRoll
        compValue += compRoll
        if userValue > 21:
            print("User's points: ", userValue)
            print("Computer's points: ", compValue)
            print("Computer wins")
        else:
            print('Points: ', userValue, sep='')
        again = get_response()

    if again == 'n':
        print("User's points: ", userValue)
        print("Computer's points: ", compValue)
        if userValue > compValue:
            print('User wins')
        elif userValue == compValue:
            print('Tie Game!')
        else:
            print('Computer wins')


def rollDice():

    userRoll = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
    compRoll = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
    return userRoll, compRoll

def get_response():

    answer = input('Do you want to roll? ')

    if answer != 'y' or answer != 'n':
        print("Invalid response. Please enter 'y' or 'n'.")
        answer = input('Do you want to roll? ')

main()
```

Comment: `if answer != 'y' or answer != 'n':` is always true. It is either not 'y' or not 'n'.

Comment: Second problem: You never returned `answer` from that funtion

Answer (score 2):

`answer != 'y' or answer != 'n':` is always true;  `or` should be `and`.

Comment: or _not answer in 'yn'_

Comment: @volcano That would make `yn` a valid input

Comment: @cricket_007, you are right, _not answer in ('y', 'n')_

Answer (score 0):

It should be `answer != 'y' and answer != 'n':`

Answer (score 0):

You're logically thinking that *"answer is not y OR n"*, but in code that is

```
not (answer == 'y' or answer == 'n')
```

Apply DeMorgans' rule you get

```
answer != 'y' and answer != 'n'
```

Perhaps you should restructure using `in`.

You'll also want to `return answer`

```
def get_response():
    while True:
        answer = input('Do you want to roll? ')

        if answer not in {'y', 'n'}:
            print("Invalid response. Please enter 'y' or 'n'.")
        else:
            return answer
```